# How to make a .jar file with multiple classes?

Tags: java, linux, windows, jar, command-prompt

Suppose i've created multiple classes and want to combine them in a single .jar file which should be portable. Now when i run that .jar file the login panel class file of my project should open first.
And for security purpose, i want that the .jar file should not be able to get extracted by someone in future.

Comment: zip the folder and rename as jar. not sure if the jar will be useful if it cannot be extracted

Comment: This is not possible. A .jar file will always be extractable, it's an ARCHIVE file (zip, with a different extension). You can obfuscate the code, you can let it contact a remote service that contains the code (and which you don't distribute), but the contents of a jar can always be read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an executable jar with multiple classes using Maven for packaging your classes. Then set the main class that serves as the application entry point using the MAVEN SHADE PLUGIN.

Read more about maven shade plugin here: [https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html][1]

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it by cmd or terminal? Does java provide commands to do these tasks?

Comment: Yes it is possible to execute maven goals from the command line. you can also use IDEs such as Intellij or eclipse also

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st question :
You can use maven-shade-plugin to build an executable jar. Just make your login panel class contain your main method.
maven-shade-plugin will put up all your dependencies and your class files in a single jar and compile them.

You can build the project by "mvn clean package"
Once build your jar will be available in target/

maven : goal

```
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>`enter code here`
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>your.main.class.file</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

For your 2nd question :
A jar file can always be extracted. You can't do much to stop that.

Answer (score 0):

For creating the executable jar you need to put all your classes in single directory. then add  manifest.txt file having written 'Main-Class: className' where class name is entry point(in your case login panel class). and then run following command
jar -cvfm newJar.jar manifest.txt *.class
It will generate newJar.jar

And use java -jar newJar.jar command to run the jar.

Comment: Do i every time need to type this command to run .jar file ??
I want that the .jar file should be run by double click on that file.

Comment: yes ,  also you can create bat file to run this jar .